# Editing a YAML file inside a Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I'm trying to use a yaml config file as a very simple flat file db for a small rails app.  The app has a single user, so I just need a way to store a username and password.  The only thing is that I'd like to be able to edit the username and password while still inside the app and not require an app restart (so I can't load the YAML file inside an initializer...).

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this?  I'm not married to the idea of using YAML, so if you have a better suggestion I'm all ears!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really are better off using a database for this sort of thing, because it's how Rails is designed to work. The Rails default database is [SQLite 3](http://www.sqlite.org/), which is a high-performance, reliable single file database.

Don't fight the defaults—use the right tool for the job.

Comment: so you'd recommend just having an entire users table for one user then?  That's what I was originally going to do but it seemed hugely overkill...perhaps it is the best solution, however.

Comment: I don't see it as being a big deal, it's not like it's going to take up a hugh amount of disk space or anything. SQLite 3 is the storage mechanism for iPhone applications, to give you some context of what else it's used for. Personally I don't see the advantage of writing a persistence mechanism when Rails already has a great solution built in i.e. ActiveRecord.

Comment: I agree, I guess I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a better way. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try iye for yaml editing on the fly. No DB needed, saves directly to file! Potentially you would just need something that tracks for file changes in your rails app and reloads your yaml file.

Here is the project page for iye: https://github.com/firmafon/iye

Answer (score -1):

http://rubyforge.org/projects/rbyaml

http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/

(http://www.yaml.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Theofanis, I'll check them out!